# How to download a single file from git-lfs using Python?

Tags: python, git, git-lfs

I am tracking some `.csv` and `.json` file using LFS in my repo, and I wish to download a single file.

Because I'm running on a cluster, which I need to initial every time, I wish that the download would happen within the code.

When I call the post request, Im getting back

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:376e3b8d27dfa7ca45c68d28466a2327832a08a92ef252502588937eeb78c8943
size  175233
```

which from what I understood is a pointer to the data.

I tried to work also with python's packages such as `giftless_client` but I didn't manage to make the download method to work.

my lfs env looks like:

```
git-lfs/3.0.2 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.17.2)
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

Endpoint=https://gecgithub01.walmart.com/usr/datasets.git/info/lfs (auth=none)
  SSH=git@gecgithub01.walmart.com:usr/datasets.git
LocalWorkingDir=/Users/usr/Dev/datasets
LocalGitDir=/Users/s0g0a87/Dev/datasets/.git
LocalGitStorageDir=/Users/usr/Dev/datasets/.git
LocalMediaDir=/Users/usr/Dev/datasets/.git/lfs/objects
LocalReferenceDirs=
TempDir=/Users/s0g0a87/Dev/datasets/.git/lfs/tmp
ConcurrentTransfers=8
TusTransfers=false
BasicTransfersOnly=false
SkipDownloadErrors=false
FetchRecentAlways=false
FetchRecentRefsDays=7
FetchRecentCommitsDays=0
FetchRecentRefsIncludeRemotes=true
PruneOffsetDays=3
PruneVerifyRemoteAlways=false
PruneRemoteName=origin
LfsStorageDir=/Users/usr/Dev/datasets/.git/lfs
AccessDownload=none
AccessUpload=none
DownloadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
UploadTransfers=basic,lfs-standalone-file,ssh
GIT_EXEC_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core
git config filter.lfs.process = "git-lfs filter-process"
git config filter.lfs.smudge = "git-lfs smudge -- %f"
git config filter.lfs.clean = "git-lfs clean -- %f"
```

Comment: Note that *Git* has no idea how to download this file. The wrapper code in Git-LFS (which isn't Git) does, but it doesn't tell Git how to do it: the wrapper does it on its own. How it does that, I don't know, though I'd suspect it's a very simple retrieve-by-path with the path derived from the oid (somehow). Look at the Git-LFS source to find out.

Comment: This part I managed to understand actually, but I couldn't figure out what is the correct path I should use, path thing didn't work `giftless_client` allegedly do it for me, but it didn't work either and I got an Error code. I also tried to find a solution in the git lfs repo, but so far no luck there either.

It's a new day, clear mind, so maybe Ill have more luck today. @torek

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the address of the file not by right clicking the file rather navigate inside the file and there would be a download tab there. Copy that link and it would work